# Best Way to Call Method With Parameter to Correspond to One of Many Strings (Ruby)

Tags: sql, ruby, string, optimization

I am trying to create a system where I call a method in a separate module from my class that executes an SQL query based on a string in that module. So for instance right now I am currently making a call in my WhLoan class as follows:

**WhLoan Class**

```
qm_code = WhQueryHelper.sql_query(:qm_code)
```

that makes a call to a method in my WhQueryHelper module which contains strings that should be executed as an sql statement depending on what was passed, in my case this being symbol. How this is sorted out in my WhQueryHelper module can be seen below:

**WhQueryHelper Module**

```
  QUALIFIED_MORTGAGE_TYPE_QUERY = " 
SELECT
  [LoanNum] AS loan_number,
  [QM_Code] AS qualified_mortgage_type
FROM
  [clg_strategy].[dbo].[QM_Codes] (NOLOCK)
"
def self.sql_query(q_sym)
 conn = Apollo::SqlServer.get_connection(CONFIG_PREFIX)
 qs = self.map_to_query_string(q_sym)
 res = conn.execute(qs).to_a
 conn.close if conn && conn.active?
 res.empty? ? nil : res 
end 

def self.map_to_query_string(q_sym)
 qs = ""
  case q_sym
  when :lock_type
    qs = LOCK_TYPE_QUERY
  when :home_indicators
    qs = HOME_INDICATORS_QUERY
  when :hpm_indicator
    qs = HIGHER_PRICED_MORTGAGE_INDICATOR_QUERY
  when :qm_code
    qs = QUALIFIED_MORTGAGE_TYPE_QUERY
  when :db_eligibility
    qs = APPLICANT_INCOME_PERCENT_OF_MEDIAN_QUERY
  when :corr_tnw_amount
    qs = CORRESPONDENT_TOTAL_NET_WORTH_AMOUNT_QUERY
  else
    raise "not a valid q_sym passed from #{caller[0]}"
  qs  
 end 
end
```

**TLDR** So essentially right now I just pass a symbol to a method in a separate module where this symbol is then run through a case statement to see which string in that module it correlates to, and then I run that string as an SQL statement. How can this life-cycle be improved so that I can create a lot of separate variables in my WhLoan class that can call the WhQueryHelper module to get the correct SQL statement return value?

Comment: You are saying that your code basically works? What do you expect to improve? What are you optimizing for? Maintainability? Readability? Memory usage?

Comment: Yes it currently works, it just seems to me like there is a way to make this process cleaner. Specifically, is there a better way to handle what I am doing beside just having a switch statement and manual symbol names passed as the parameters to WhQueryHelper.sql_query(). I have the Query strings in another module and not my class because it takes up too much space and is not clean. So readability and maintainability would be the main things I am wondering about.

Comment: I would suggest storing each SQL query in a file on its own and name the files by their current `q_sym`. Than the code only needs to check if a file with that name exists and if it does then load its content.

Comment: Ya that would be a good work around and cleaner thanks

Comment: For code that works but needs improvement (as opposed to code that doesn't work and needs fixing), the [codereview.se] community is much better equipped.

Comment: Why not just store the query strings as return values from method calls? e.g. `module WhQueryHelper; def self.qm_code; YOUR_QUERY_STRING_HERE; end; end` and then just use `qs = self.public_send(:qm_code)` ? You could also just use a large `Hash` of {code: "query string"} as a constant and then use `qs = YOUR_HASH[code]`